# Update db/migrate after manually updating models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, rake

For example i have this model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :order
end
```

Then when i did `rake db:migrate` it created this **db/migrate/20120825132038_create_products.rb**:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.integer :order
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But it all happend cuz i used `rails generate Product order:integer name:string`

Now after i go to Product model and changes it manually to:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :order, :category_id

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :category
end
```

How can i auto update the **db/migrate/20120825132038_create_products.rb** with the updates?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you ran `rake db:migrate`, it **did not** create `db/migrate/20120825132038_create_products.rb`. That migration file was created when you ran

```
rails generate Product order:integer name:string
```

`attr_accessible` has nothing to do with migrating your database.

**I strongly recommend you read the Rails Guide on *[Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)*, as well as the section on *[Mass Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)* which discusses `attr_accessible`.**

To generate a *new* migration file *(since the one mentioned in your Question has already been processed by the previous `rake db:migrate` command you mentioned running)*, run

```
rails g migration AddCategoryIdToProduct category_id:integer
```

This should generate a new migration with contents like

```
class AddCategoryIdToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :category_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Running `rake db:migrate` again now will process this migration file, adding the new `category_id` integer column to your `products` table.

Comment: Thanks for the great explenation!
But each time i want to add an attribute/property (whatever you call it) to a model i need to use the rails g migration and create a new class?

Comment: If the migration's already been applied to the database, **yes**. A model is nothing more than an interface through which you can interact with your database. It does not manipulate the **structure** of your database; that's what migrations are for. Adding a column to a table will automatically make the new attribute methods available within the associated model.

Comment: Yes. Always create a new migration - even for just one column. Never go back and edit an old migration. It's a good habit!
Trust me, your future colleagues will thank me for making sure you follow this practice.

Answer (score 7):

You can redo a migration by running

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20121031143418 #insert the timestamp on migration
```

You can also redo a migration (runs up and down, but only works if you have an up and down, which you won't when you just have a change)

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```